# How to generate light random colours in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have stored procedure running in T-SQL 2012 and got filed to generate random Hex colours which is all working fine except generated Hex code are in dark colour combination like dark blue, dark green etc. I need to generate light colour scheme, how can I do that.

```
SELECT
RecordId,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3), 2)as [BarColour]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you use will produce light colors as well as dark colors. If you're only getting dark colors, it's just bad luck.

A starting point for generating only light colors would be to do something like this. It randomly generates the RGB values and concatenates them into your hex codes.

```
SELECT CONCAT(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 135) + 120) AS VARBINARY),2),2),RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 135) + 120) AS VARBINARY),2),2),RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),CAST((ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 135) + 120) AS VARBINARY),2),2))
```

I ran this repeatedly to output results 10 at a time and I got back a range of light grey-hues and pastels. This method won't give you any pure colors though as it completely avoids the low range values.